# where to buy Blocks of dry Ice in the UK

Tags: uk, sound-design

Does anyone know where its possible to buy blocks of dry ice in the uk?

Tried google but want to make sure Im not purchasing something useless

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you don't find anything, a close second to buying dry ice is purchasing ice cream over the internet.

It arrives in a styrofoam box with a ton of dry ice inside of it.

If you buy a couple cartons, you'll have a treat to eat while you play with a bunch of dry ice!

Answer (score 3):

http://www.chillistick.co.uk/dry-ice-products-c-318.html

Answer (score 1):

Any theatre lighting hire/sales company will sell dry ice.  If you let me know where you live I can suggest somewhere local.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys, just wanted to make sure I wasn't buying something absolutely useless with the same name.

Thank you very much for the help